# Can someone please help me identify this antenna/rod part? It attaches to the bottom of a brick

Tags: part-identification

These red antenna-like pieces have four flanges at the base.  The base does NOT fit on top of a stud, but rather it will fit the underside/bottom side of brick.  The two pieces can also be connected to each other to extend the length and fit in lego people's hands.[image]

Comment: I'm pretty sure we had some of these when I was a kid. I remember that they are not LEGO brand, but I can't remember what other toy they came from.

Comment: I think they are from one of the early lego sets, except I'm not sure which one. It might be one of the earlier legoland sets.

Answer (score 2):

These bars are not referenced as Lego bricks by BrickLink, neither by Brickset.

- The [complete list of existing bars](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogList.asp?catType=P&catID=46) is available on the BrickLink
  catalogue for example;
- Brickset proposes a list of all [Signs, Flags, and Poles](http://brickset.com/parts/category-System-Signs-Flags-And-Poles) since the last 27 years and that bar is not included.

Therefore I believe these particular bars are not from Lego.